# Renaming a row in dataset

Tags: r

I have over 100 individuals in my data with 8 entries each. How do I rename the variable in the second entry for each individual as specified below:

**Original data**

```
id   cd
1    PC
1    PC
1    Lab1
1    Lab2
1    Lab3
1    CS
1    CS
1    V
2    PC
2    PC
2    Lab1
2    Lab2
2    Lab3
2    CS
2    CS
2    V
3    PC
3    PC
3    Lab1
3    Lab2
3    Lab3
3    CS
3    CS
3    V
```

What I want is to rename the second entry for each subject to PC_Mean

```
id   cd
1    PC
1    PC_Mean
1    Lab1
1    Lab2
1    Lab3
1    CS
1    CS_Mean
1    V
2    PC
2    PC_Mean
2    Lab1
2    Lab2
2    Lab3
2    CS
2    CS_Mean
2    V
3    PC
3    PC_Mean
3    Lab1
3    Lab2
3    Lab3
3    CS
3    CS_Mean
3    V
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your data is regular ie, 8 rows per individual, here is a way using the modulus operator, `%%`:

```
# test matrix
tempMat <- matrix(0, 24, 1)
rownames(tempMat) <- paste(1:24, letters[1:24], sep=".")


rownames(tempMat)[1:nrow(tempMat) %% 8 == 2] <-
                    paste0(rownames(tempMat)[1:nrow(tempMat) %% 8 == 2], "_mean")
```